# Database Health - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If someone asks me to check the database health in a particular SQL Server database, which has been running for couple of years, what are the possible areas that I need to check? Do we have any tools to support for that?

Kindly provide some recommended links also to refer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things (at a bare minimum):

1. Make sure that backups are being taken on a regular basis and that at least once a full restore was done from the backups and that the restore was verified to contain valid, up to date, data.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx
2. Run 'DBCC checkdb' on the instance. It will take a while and can be a resource hog (you may want to run it at night or over a weekend.) Be very careful in reading the results and figuring out what to do if it detects errors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/checkdb-from-every-angle/

3. If you do the above you may be held responsible for any, and all, issues that will ever occur to SQL Server including data entry errors.